# Why does WHERE work in Web UI but not in gsutil?

Tags: google-bigquery, gsutil

The following works when I query a table using `bigquery` web ui:

```
select * from my_table where record_datetime > '2017-01-01 00:00:00' limit 10
```

but when I run the same command using `bq` it breaks:

```
bq query  --use_legacy_sql=false select * FROM `mlp-1385.data.historical_bk`  where record_datetime > '2017-01-01 00:00:00' limit 10
```

and I get the error:

```
Error in query string: Error processing job
'mlp-1385:bqjob_XXXXXXXX': WHERE clause should return
WHERE clause should return
type BOOL, but returns FLOAT64
```

When I remove the where clause, everything works in both the webui and `gsutil`.

How can I fix my command line query?

Answer (score 0):

When running queries in the google's `gsutil` you must escape `<` and `>` with the `^` operator, otherwise the command line looks at them as a redirect.

So for example `<` becomes `^<` and `>` becomes `^>`.

So my command line command should be:

```
bq query  --use_legacy_sql=false select * FROM `mlp-1385.data.historical_bk`  where record_datetime ^> '2017-01-01 00:00:00' limit 10
```

Comment: You can also pipe the input from a file, which is often a better approach so that you don't need to worry about escaping. `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < my_query.sql`